# Как связать 2 таблицы в MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

Нужно связать 2 таблицы по id.

```sql
CREATE TABLE
staff (
id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
age SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL,
salary int(15) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

и

```sql
CREATE TABLE
staff2 (
id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
city CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Не могли бы вы объяснить как происходит связывание таблиц, что для этого нужно, какие ограничения. Не могу найти информацию по этому вопросу для MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Ищите по ключевым словам "внешний ключ", "FOREIGN KEY".
А ваш пример - два счетчика связать - выходит за рамки моего понимания. :-)

Comment: Только FOREIGN KEY, ежели склероз не изменяет, работает только для engine=innodb. Если бы Вы написали, что Вы понимаете под словом "связать", можно было бы ответить конкретней.